# Python Hypothesis package: can I ensure that certain values are used?

Tags: python, testing, python-hypothesis

## Problem Statement

Below is a toy example that is close to what I am trying to do.

```py
@given(
    idx_start=integers(min_value=0, max_value=100000),
    idx_window=integers(min_value=0, max_value=100000),
)
def test_calc_max(conftest_df, idx_start, idx_window):
    row_idxs = conftest_df.index[idx_start : (idx_start + idx_window)]
    assert calc_max(conftest_df.loc[row_idxs, "my_column"]) >= 0
```

`conftest_df` is a Dataframe that I am making available in my `conftest.py` fixture file, which represents a portion of real data that I am using for my package.

This dataframe has **very few** `NaN` values in it.  I want to use `hypothesis` because, well, it's awesome and I strongly believe it is the right way to do things.

But I also want to make sure that the methods and functions under test work for NaN's.  I don't really want to just say `NaN`s, something else might come up in the future (say, a number that uses a comma instead of a period to represent a decimal).

---

## Ideal Solution via `hypothesis`

I would rather be able to do something like this:

```py
@given(
    idx_start=integers(min_value=0, max_value=100000, includes=[5, 4000, 80000]),
    idx_window=integers(min_value=0, max_value=100000, includes=[20]),
)
.
.
.
```

And have a way to *ensure* that certain values are considered via the `includes` argument.

I know that `hypothesis` keeps track of failing values, but it does not seem to guarantee their use, from my experience.

Is there a way to do what I would like?

Comment: we can combine `strategie.sampled_from([list of edge cases]) | strategy_for_common_case` and according to the rule examples from the first strategy will be generated more likely than the second one

Comment: also we can decorate specific test with [`example`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reproducing.html#hypothesis.example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@example` decorator to ensure that certain examples are being tested.

This is the example from [hypothesis's quick start guide](https://hypothesis-test-zhd.readthedocs.io/en/build/quickstart.html):

```
from hypothesis import given, example
from hypothesis.strategies import text

@given(text())
@example('')
def test_decode_inverts_encode(s):
    assert decode(encode(s)) == s
```

Here, `@example('')` is ensuring that the test will be run with the empty string as an example.

I haven't fully understood the details of your scenario, but maybe you are able to adapt this example to your needs on your own.